# Htaccess Internal Server Error (Internal Redirect)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

So this is a quick question.

```
RewriteRule ^/submit/(.*)$ /include/page/form/$1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

The code above should be internally redirecting forms (POST) submitted to domain.com/submit/name to /domain.com/page/form/name.php. That's it but it keeps not working. I don't know why but I'm sure the solution is simple.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Any message or anything?

Comment: @Howlin I think OP is pointed out the error in the title

Comment: If you want to point to `domain.com/page/form/name.php` then why you have included the `include` word in your target rule? Your expected target doesn't have `include`.

Comment: Oh, I missed out the include bit. There's a folder called include before the page folder. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash as seen below:

```
RewriteRule ^submit/(.*)$ /include/page/form/$1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

It is written in [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) that: a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

If you’re putting […] rules in an .htaccess file […] the directory prefix (/) is removed from the REQUEST_URI variable, as all requests are automatically assumed to be relative to the current directory.